# How to group generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to specify constraint *groups* to a generic method, but I'm not sure that this is even possible in C#. If it is, I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax. Currently I have the following:

```
public TOut GetResponse<TOut, TIn>(TIn message)
    where TOut : BaseMessageResponse
    where TIn  : BaseMessageRequest
```

Which functions perfectly well. However I don't actually send or receive base class messages, I have derived classes instead. What I really want is to be able to declare groups so that I can tell at compile time if I have a mismatched request and response type. So what I want would be something like this:

```
public TOut GetResponse<TOut, TIn>(TIn message)
    (where TOut : Derived1Response
    where TIn : Derived1Request)
    (where TOut : Derived2Response
    where TIn : Derived2Request)
```

Is this something that can be done in a single method definition?

There is another solution, which is to have a method definition for each of the pairs of request/response objects, and have each of those call the common generic method I have now, like so:

```
public Derived1Response GetResponse(Derived1Request request)
{
    return GetResponse<Derived1Response, Derived1Request>(request);
}

public Derived2Response GetResponse(Derived2Request request)
{
    return GetResponse<Derived2Response, Derived2Request>(request);
}
```

This would bloat the code however, which defeats the purpose of using generics to begin with.

Comment: Why do you want to specify the types (or why do they need to be specific) when on the other hand you restrict them? This is probably the real problem here.

Comment: @CSharpie It's because of the API I'm interfacing with. The request and response objects have all their properties defined by a third party, which are being serialized to and from JSON. For a specific request object, I expect to receive a specific response object. This is why I want to restrict them in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I would move the generic definition out to the class level and use separate instances for the different request/response types.

e.g.

```
public myClass<TOut, TIn>
    where TOut : BaseMessageResponse
    where TIn  : BaseMessageRequest
{
    public TOut GetResponse(TIn)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
var derived1Processing = new myClass<Derived1Response, Derived1Request>();
var derived2Processing = new myClass<Derived2Response, Derived2Request>();
```

Comment: If I had structured things differently, this would work. However I have a parent class that stores connection and authentication information, so that it doesn't need to be specified for each individual call. This would still permit such reuse, but with more granularity than I'm looking for.

Comment: Due to the design I chose, I ended up using the alternative I originally described in my question, which is a discrete method for each individual pair or request/response types. However since your answer is also an acceptable solution (just not in my specific case) I'm accepting yours.